# Error Undefined offset en PHP

Tags: php, array

Necesito separar los elementos de un array de acuerdo a su tipo e imprimirlos en una lista.

```php
<?php

$d[0] = 13;
$d[1] = 133;
$d[2] = 45;
$d[3] = "Hice 89 lagartijas";
$d[4] = 778;
$d[5] = 67;
$d[6] = "Que onda";
$d[7] = 456;
$d[8] = 34;
$d[9] = 645;

for($i=0; $i<=9; $i++){
    switch($d){
        case is_numeric($d[$i]):
            $s[$i] = $d[$i];
            break;
        case is_string($d[$i]):
            $k[$i] = $d[$i];
            break;
    }
}
echo "Numeros <BR>";

for($i = 0; $i<=9; $i++){
    echo "$s[$i] <br>";
}
echo "Textos <BR>";

for($i = 0; $i<=9; $i++){
    echo "$k[$i] <br>";
}
```

Comment: No encuentro ningún problema con el código de tu pregunta.

Comment: Me sale sto: 
Numeros 
13 
133 
45 

NOTICE Undefined offset: 3 on line number 25

778 
67 

NOTICE Undefined offset: 6 on line number 25

456 
34 
645 
Textos 

NOTICE Undefined offset: 0 on line number 30


NOTICE Undefined offset: 1 on line number 30


NOTICE Undefined offset: 2 on line number 30

Hice 89 lagartijas 

NOTICE Undefined offset: 4 on line number 30


NOTICE Undefined offset: 5 on line number 30

Que onda 

NOTICE Undefined offset: 7 on line number 30

Comment: Por algún motivo el `PHP con Windows` no me arroja ningún error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observando tu código a detalle, el problema es al momento de evaluar la cantidad de elementos que tenga los `Arrays` de números y letras.

```
<?php

$d[0] = 13;
$d[1] = 133;
$d[2] = 45;
$d[3] = "Hice 89 lagartijas";
$d[4] = 778;
$d[5] = 67;
$d[6] = "Que onda";
$d[7] = 456;
$d[8] = 34;
$d[9] = 645;

$indiceNumeros = 0;
$indiceLetras = 0;
for($i=0; $i<=9; $i++){
    switch($d){
        case is_numeric($d[$i]):            
            $s[$indiceNumeros] = $d[$i];
            $indiceNumeros++;
            break;
        case is_string($d[$i]):
            $k[$indiceLetras] = $d[$i];
            $indiceLetras++;
            break;
    }
}
echo "Numeros <BR>";

for($i = 0; $i<count($s); $i++){
    echo "$s[$i] <br>";
}
echo "Textos <BR>";

for($i = 0; $i<count($k); $i++){
    echo "$k[$i] <br>";
}   
?>
```

> **Numeros** *Contiene solo 8 elementos y no 9*
>
> 13, 133, 45, 778, 67, 456, 34, 645
>
> **Textos** *Contiene solo 2 elementos y no 9*
>
> Hice 89 lagartijas, Que onda

---

**Recomendación:**

Evalúa por la cantidad de elementos que tiene un `array` con la función [`count`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.count.php) y declara variables para los índices consecutivos.

En el caso que no necesites declarar variables para identificar los índices consecutivos otra manera de insertar elementos a un `array` es usando la función [`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php).

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
$pila = array("naranja", "plátano");
array_push($pila, "manzana", "arándano");
print_r($pila);
?>
```

Comment: Buena respuesta. Se podría simplificar un poco porque los índices no son necesarios a la hora de insertar

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro acabo de complementar con un ejemplo usando `array_push`.

Comment: ni siquiera necesitas array push. Bastaría `$k[] = $d[$i]`;

Comment: @amenadiel lo tendré en cuenta =)..