# Undefined offset al pasar datos de un checkbox

Tags: php

Al ejecutar este código me indica Undefined offset.
Haciendo un volcado de variables, descubrí que el problema está en un checkbox `$informarUP[$fila]`, que si está seleccionado no da el error y si no está seleccionado, da el error.

Lo que no logro es que ese checkbox tenga un valor si no está seleccionado.

```html
<?php
//...

foreach($idfila as $fila) {
$pdesid = uniqid('pdes_');  

if(isset($idfila)){
$queryPedidoDesglose = "INSERT INTO pedidos_desglose (id_pedido_desglose,id_pedido, id_pedido_trafico, direccion_inicio, hora_inicio, hora_inicio_hasta, descripcion, hora_rendicion, informar) VALUES ('$pdesid','$peid', '$id_pedido_nuevo', '$destino[$fila]', '$pedidohs[$fila]', '$pedidohshasta[$fila]', '$pedido_desarrollo[$fila]', '$rendicionhs[$fila]', '$informarUP[$fila]')";

if ($mysqli->query($queryPedidoDesglose) === TRUE){}; 


//...
}
}
?>
```

Comment: muestra un volcado de los arrays  $destino, $pedidohs, $pedidohshasta, $pedido_desarrollo, $rendicionhs y $informarUP y muesta el valor de $fila en el momento del error.

Comment: Ya agregué el volcado de las variables

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Error Undefined offset en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50342/error-undefined-offset-en-php)

Comment: No se sabe qué parte del volcado corresponde a qué array, asegúrate que ninguno esté vacío y por eso no lo esté mostrando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empecemos por el principio, qué quiere decir el error "Undefined offset":

Imagina que creas un array como el siguiente:

```
$fruta[0]= “naranja”;
$fruta[1]=”manzana”;
```

y luego en alguna parte de tu código intentas leer el valor $fruta[2] por ejemplo :

```
echo $fruta[2];
```

Allí está el problema. Como nunca se ha definido un tercer valor para el array `$fruta[]`, `$fruta[2]` está fuera del rango de valores del array que solo tiene asignados valores para `$fruta[0]` y para `$fruta[1]`. **En el sistema de manejo de errores de PHP eso es "Undefined offset".**

Ahora bien, analizando tu código, en la línea que te lanza el error tienes varios índices de array que son variables, alguno de ellos seguramente cae fuera del rango de valores definidos para ese array, estos son:

```
$destino[$fila]
$pedidohs[$fila]
$pedidohshasta[$fila]
$pedido_desarrollo[$fila]
$rendicionhs[$fila]
$informarUP[$fila]
```

### Cómo solucionarlo?

Debes encontrar cuál o cuáles de esos valores está provocando el error **"Undefined offset"**. Una forma de investigar cuál es el índice problemático sería comentar la línea que te da el error y, en diferentes líneas de tu archivo ejecutar:

```
echo $destino[$fila];
echo $pedidohs[$fila]
echo $pedidohshasta[$fila]
echo $pedido_desarrollo[$fila]
echo $rendicionhs[$fila]
echo $informarUP[$fila]
```

De esta manera dependiendo de en qué línea te arroje el error **"Undefined offset"** sabrás cuál o cuáles de esos índices te están provocando un **"Undefined offset"**.

En tal caso deberías en tu script primero comprobar que exista el valor, ejemplo:

```
if (isset $informarUP[$fila] ) {
 $informarUP = $informarUP[$fila];
}else{
 $informarUPchecked = ''; // o cualquier otro valor que desees
}
```

y en el query en lugar de insertar directamente al valor que viene del array $informarUP[$fila] insertas la variable $informarUPchecked.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación. El problema es un checkbox que cuando no está seleccionado, da ese error.
Aún sigo con el inconveniente. Si tienes alguna sugerencia, será bienvenida.

Comment: De nada, es un gusto poder ayudar. Considera editar la pregunta o bien abrir otra con el problema más detallado ahora que sabes más sobre el error, eso hará que sea más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Fíjate en la parte de mi respuesta: if (isset $informarUP[$fila] ){...} alli puedes asignar un valor que quieras si el checkbox no esta seleccionado.

Answer (score 1):

Para que un checkbox tenga valor cuando no esta seleccionado se puede trucar poniendo **antes** un campo hidden con nombre igual que el checkbox y el valor que deseas en caso de no estar chequeado.

De esta forma si no se marca el check se enviará el valor de campo oculto.

Por ejemplo:

```
<input type="hidden" name="acuerdo" value="0">
<label>Marca si estas de acuerdo: </label><input type="checkbox" name="acuerdo" value="1">
<input type="submit" name="continuar" value="Continuar">
```

De esta manera **siempre** te llegará la variable llamada *acuerdo*, con valor 1 o con valor 0.

Es un truco un poco sucio, solo recomendable para salir del paso rápido de forma temporal.

Sería mejor solucionar la incidencia en el script que recibe los datos, algo así:

```
 if (isset($_REQUEST['acuerdo']) {
     $acuerdo = $_REQUEST['acuerdo'] ;
 } else {
     $acuerdo = 0;
 }
```

o en su versión reducida:

```
 $acuerdo = isset($_REQUEST['acuerdo'])?$_REQUEST['acuerdo']:0;
```

Comment: Me gusta este truco, pero destaco tu línea "Es un truco un poco sucio, solo recomendable para salir del paso rápido de forma temporal."
Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolví con `empty`, validando dentro del `foreach`.

```
$informarUP = $_POST['informar'];

foreach($idfila as $fila) {
if(empty($informarUP[$fila])){
$Informar = "NO";
}else{
$Informar = "SI";   
}
}
```